# GradleException. Flutter SDK not found

Tags: gradle, flutter, sdk

I have updated my flutter sdk from pubspec.yaml file. I clicked on Flutter update button from there and then it downloaded and updated.
**But after that I am unable to run any of my app projects.**
Anyone can please tell me, How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an android studio then try below things:

```
File -> Settings > Languages & Frameworks -> flutter
```

then try manually to fix it if it is not detected :(

Comment: Tried that, but it doesn’t help my problem. 